# Match History relational database

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database, relationships

I am new to Microsoft access and lack some database knowledge and logic. I am working on a project that requires me to create 5 tables and include one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationship. So, this is my idea, I am trying to create a simplified version of LoL (League of Legends) match history database. So far I created these tables, but I just can't really understand the logic. I really need some help.

```
Tables are:

**Players**

[PK]PlayersID

SummonerName

Level

Rank

Devision

**Champions**

[PK]ChampionsID

Name

Kills

Deaths

Assists

MinionSlained

**Map**

[PK]MapID

MapName

Size

Mode


**Time**

[PK]MatchID

Year

Month

Date

**MatchHistory**

[PK]MatchID

PlayerName

Champion

Result

Map

Time
```

I am trying to make the **Players** and **Champions** the parents of the relationship and then **MatchHistory** will be their child and **TIme** and **Map** will be the child of **MatchHistory**. I suppose both **Time** and **Map** will be one-to-one to **MatchHistory**, **Players** to **Champions** will be one-to-many? I am really not sure if I am doing it right, because this is my first time creating a database myself, I'll really appreciate more help and pointers:)

Comment: What is *"devision"* in the "Players" table? Besides... Why you've created a table for "Time" entity? Don't you think it would be better create that entity like an Map's attribute (or maybe MatchHistory). Unfortunately, I can't figure the "problem". Can you explain it more deep? I don't know anything of LoL.

Comment: By the way... The Player-Champions relation could be one-to-many (from Players to Champions), if and only if, one player could be many champions; and one champion could be only one player (as you can see - or maybe for me - this not has sense. I think that the Player-Champions relation should be one-to-one... But as I said you before, I don't know anything about LoL).

Comment: devision is just the ranking system for the players, so its not related to the game. So, basically the game is played by 10 players each as one champion through out the game. The time is just for record the date the match was played.

Comment: http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/3756/scizorhistory.jpg

this is how the match history looks like for individual player
I am trying to do a match history for a single player, not a match history that contain all the satas of all the players played that match lol

Comment: One player could have more than one champion? Or just one champion? Besides... The "champions" are types? For example: The champion of fire or something like that?
One more question: You want to store some information about the battles? I think so, not?

Comment: One player could own more than one champion in their account, but they can only use one champion per game(match). The "type" field just meant which type of champion it is, such as ranged, fighter, support, etc. Umm...It is just an assignment to show that I know how to use access, and create those three types of relationship, so I wouldn't go that far, even my TA asked me to simplify it....